# Android SQLite (1) no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

i am pretty new to programming in android and here is my first try to create a sqlite database. Every time i call the insert()-Method, i get the error "(1) no such table: songs.db". I searched this error but i couldn't find any solution. Here is my Class:

```
public class HearOpenHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_SONGS = "songs";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_INTERPRET = "interpret";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String COLUMN_URI = "uri";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "songs.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " 
        + TABLE_SONGS + "(" 
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + COLUMN_INTERPRET + " text not null, " 
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, " 
        + COLUMN_URI + " text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_DROP = "drop table if exists " + TABLE_SONGS;

public HearOpenHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}


public void insert(String interpret, String title, String uri) {

    long rowId;

    // Open database
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    // Data which should be stored
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_INTERPRET, interpret);
    values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
    values.put(COLUMN_URI, uri);

    // insert in database
    rowId = db.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, values);

    if(rowId == -1)
        Log.d(HearOpenHandler.class.getName(), "Error while inserting values into database");

}

}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

This

```
rowId = db.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, values);
```

should probably be

```
rowId = db.insert(TABLE_SONGS, null, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the row means inside the table. Your query of insert is pointing to the Db, which is explained in the error.

```
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

which is `songs` , its looking for a table name - `songs.db` instead

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct but keep this tip in your mind to have an eye on the eclipse's tips, see this:

[image: eclipse help]